# Como añadir font-family a un svg en un servidor sin topografias? Node JS backend

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, svg

Tengo un problema a la hora de generar SVGs con texto. En un servicio backend alojado en GCP con kubernetes, el servidor no dispone de tipologías de página (o al menos eso creo).

Por ello, necesito ser capaz de generar imágenes con texto y para ello hasta ahora creaba un SVG con una etiqueta text en su interior y con la librería Sharp, hago una composición con otros elementos para generar una imagen. Cuando el servicio lo corro en mi local, la imagen aparece correctamente con el texto, sin embargo, al subirla a GCP, solo aparecen cuadrados blancos como si no hubiera una tipografía por defecto.

He intentado añadir una tipografía personalizada a mi SVG, pero Sharp no la procesa.

El SVG que intento generar es algo así:

```
 <svg width="320" height="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <text x="50%" y="80%" class="title" fill="white"  font-size="30px"  text-anchor="middle" >Texto</text>
</svg>
```

Pero aplicando un estilo de fuente personalizado.

Como debo hacerlo?

Comment: Tienes el `fill="white"` por eso se te ve todo blanco